# Google sheet api php - non CLI usage - avoid confirmation prompt

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I've followed [this official guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php), but now I'd like to not use a CLI for my application. The following confirmation prompt code is not suitable for browser usage:

```
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

It prompts inside the browser but we cannot enter anything (not like using CLI)

[image]
Is there any alternative auth I can use to connect with my google sheet, and how to do that ?

Comment: If you want to access Sheets on behalf of an end user, you always have to click through the confirmation screen, no way around it. I'd carefully follow the tutorial again, from the very beginning, making sure you're using the right credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having the same question, using google service account key will fix it, in fact, we won't have the token refresh code anymore. how to do?

- [create a service account key](https://github.com/juampynr/google-spreadsheet-reader)
- download the key as json, assuming you have something named `service_account-secret.json`
- just use `setAuthConfig` to authentificate as follow:

```
$apiOptions = [
    'application_name' => 'My App Name',
    'credential_path' => __DIR__.'/service_account-secret.json'
];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(array_get($apiOptions, 'application_name', 'Google Sheets API PHP'));
$client->setScopes(array_get($apiOptions, 'scope', Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS));
$client->setAuthConfig(array_get($apiOptions, 'credential_path'));
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

That way, we don't need to use the token as described on https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php